# JQuery Error datepicker is not a function

Tags: jquery

I have a simple code that once worked, after i tried to make changes and rolled back I get the following error:

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):25)
at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
```

My code is:

```
<script src="./resources/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( function() {
    if ( $('[type="date"]').prop('type') != 'date' ) {
        $('[type="date"]').datepicker();
    }

});
</script>
```

Modifications were:

```
 <script>
    $( function() {
        if ( $('[type="date"]').prop('type') != 'date' ) {
            $('[type="date"]').datepicker();
        }

        if ( $('[type="time"]').prop('type') != 'time' ) {
            $('[type="time"]').timepicker();
        }

    });
    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you included [jQuery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) ?
 Here is a [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqueryui).

Comment: What is this code trying to achieve? I might guess perhaps you forgot to include jquery ui script.

Comment: no as before it worked fine even without

Comment: *«it worked fine even without»* I'm sure not, since it isn't part of the basic jQuery library.

Comment: The code I want to achieve is that is in the last exaple with oth datepicker and timepicker. The problem is that before,just with datepicker and without jquery-ui libarary it worked....and later no more...

Comment: If that's all of your markup, it definitely didn't work before. `datepicker()` is neither a native jQuery or JS function... You need to include either jQuery UI, or the plugin JS you're working with.

Comment: ok I will try with UI . Should I include alseo Jquery-ui.css?

Comment: Yes, include the .css too.

Comment: Sorry one more question: may I use version min?

Comment: The min versions will load a couple ms faster... But you won't notice the difference.

Comment: After including JqueryUI libarary the error was changed to `timepicker` is not a function...and still no effect(even without timepicker) on the page... The idea was to make alternative on MacOs for html input type=date and type=time

Comment: timePicker ??? It's not included in jQuery-UI. It *may* be [this one](http://timepicker.co/). You mentionned an example... Don't you have explanations with it?

Comment: Ok lets forget about timepicker() I thought it is native....still the date picker doesn't show me anything in the input field `<input type="date" ng-model="from" required>`

Comment: Use `type="text"` Here is an example : https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/BRMLGa

Comment: nope....now it doesn't work even on windows even though your example I may see...on any browser